# Threading Event handlers

Tags: c#, multithreading, events

I'd like to thread this below event

```
skype.MessageStatus += new _ISkypeEvents_MessageStatusEventHandler(skype_MessageStatus);

private void skype_MessageStatus(ChatMessage msg, TChatMessageStatus status)
{
}
```

reason is so I can call thread sleep in `skype_MessageStatus` without putting the main thread to sleep.

I really don't know a better way to ask this, so hope this is good enough.

Comment: What are you using `Thread.Sleep` for?

Comment: This looks like an X/Y problem. There is no conceivable use for Sleep() in a status-changed event.

Comment: What does the reason matter? I'm handling something inside that event that I want sleep's for. Lol.

Comment: The reason is we usually don't like to help someone in making a bad solution even worse. But you're right, there are lots of LOLs in learning things the hard way.

Comment: This is a bot, if the bot replies instantly it defeats the purpose. Understand now? lol

Answer (score 2):

Use a Lambda to queue it to the threadpool.

```
skype.MessageStatus += m => ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => skype_MessageStatus(m));
```

Or you can make two skype_MessageStatus methods, one that calls the second using the ThreadPool:

```
skype_MessageStatus += skypeMessageStatus;

private void skype_MessageStatus(m) 
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(skype_MessageStatusImpl, m);
}                               

private void skype_MessageStatusImpl(object m)
{
    ...
}
```

Also best practice is not to use a `Thread.Sleep` but instead set a timer.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx for various timers in .NET.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using Thread.Sleep() consider using [Task.Delay() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194845.aspx) to schedule a delayed callback:

```
 skype.MessageStatus += (sender, args)=> 
      Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).ContinueWith((t)=> CallAfterDelay());
```